# Announcement: StackExchange API Development Wiki

Tags: support, dev-tip

> ### RIP August 24, 2010 - April 26, 2013
>
> Due to lack of interest and the increasing burden of maintenance, I have decided to close down this wiki. Most of the information that it contains is either outdated or repeated elsewhere.

There was quite a bit of discussion on [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/1428/is-it-really-worth-to-implicitly-discourage-documentation-of-api-library-usage) question in regards to the so-called `dev-tip` questions / posts here. Being the type of person who wants to step in and help in times of confusion (confusion being the lack of proper facilities for handling these questions), I decided to create something myself.

So here goes...

I downloaded, installed, and configured [MediaWiki](http://mediawiki.org/) on my server. The idea is you can post ANY valuable API related tips / advice there.

Here's the link:

http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/wiki/

**Enjoy!**

---

**Note:** Please don't forget to sign up before posting... it helps me know how the site is being used / its popularity / etc.

Comment: Ah, good ol' Media Wiki

Comment: @Farseeker: But did you like it? Is it something you would find useful?

Comment: @george, yeah I think I would. I've already gone an added a page to it about gzipped data, because I wasn't very good at reading instructions so I raged against the machine for a good few hours finding that out.

Comment: @Farseeker: So that was you :) Thanks - it was much appreciated. Feel free to add tutorials or create a custom page for your app or whatever you feel like!

Comment: What is content licensed under?

Comment: @Simon: Same as StackExchange - [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/).

Comment: @Alexandre: Good idea! I'll add that very soon. **Very** soon.

Comment: If you add the Dynamic page List extension, the static list of dev tips can be made, well dynamic. Also why not create some script to 
convert the dev-tip questions into wiki articles using the API :)