# Using the API directly from JavaScript

Tags: support, api, javascript

Is there any way I can use the API directly from JavaScript without any Server side proxy? I know of the inter-domain restrictions, but can we do it somehow in case of facebook API right?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by making a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) request. This works by returning the results of a query in a `<script>` tag that invokes a callback.

You can find more information about it [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/891/how-to-call-the-api-via-jsonp-in-plain-old-javascript).